# Displaying high resolution image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a really high resolution images (e.g. [this one](http://www.digitalfishlibrary.org/library/ViewImage.php?id=1751))
that needs to be viewed.

I would like to either fit it into the browser screen or have user scroll around the picture (without changing the image).

What are some good ways to do such things?
I'm guessing that there is a way to do this with CSS (using width/height) or Javascript. I'm just wondering what are some other solutions or best solutions using CSS/Javascript.

Another good way of doing this can be have some type of control that allows users to zoom in/out and move around the high res picture. Should I just use GoogleMaps API for this?

Comment: the answer depends on whether the images are of such hi resolution that it becomes unreasonable to download them entirely to your browser. the example you gave is right on the hairy edge of acceptable delay in loading, but I don't know your application so might be ok...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but here is an example:
http://www.visual-blast.com/javascript/panoramic-photoviewer-in-javascript/
Also, just google open source photo management for some examples and ideas.  Another option is to use flash.  It is trivial do do this with an embedded flash module.  There are probably some open source flash photoviewers too, if you need ideas.

Answer (score 0):

for fitting into the browser window, you can use this:

```
 var yourImage = document.getElementById('imageid');   
 yourImage.style.width = window.innerWidth+"px";
```

or loop through all images

```
var yourImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < yourImages.length;i++){    
     yourImages[i].style.width = window.innerWidth+"px";   
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that the picture gets cut off for some reason. User needs to expand the screen to see the rest portion instead of scrolling. Images are usually over 3000px wide, and I don't think users would like to expand their browser to that size

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the free Google Maps API. Use one of the many tile cutters to chop up your image and then show your high resolution photo like a Google map - people can zoom in, out and pan around. Cutting your image up like this makes it harder to steal too!

[Read this blog post for more info](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2009/01/use_google_maps_to_view_highres_pho.html?CMP=OTC-0D6B48984890)

Comment: I have been trying to do this, but the problem is now that I am trying to use Google Maps API I need to automate the image cutting process for images that I have in the file system. Do you know if this is possible? or any help on doing that?

Comment: this link is broken now too